# Transforming a ODE into a autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

In the book I'am reading about ODE there is a section that explains how to transform a system of ode to a first order system, by introducing a new variable y.
So if i can solve the ODE for the highest derivative
$y^{(k)}(t)=f(t,y^{(1)},..,y^{(k-1)})$ and define

$$x_1=y$$
$$x_2=y^{(1)}$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$x_k=y^{(k-1)}$$

But now it says that we could even define $z=(t,x)$ and make the system autonomous.
I don't really understand the last part.
Taking for example
$y'(t)=ty(t)$
I would set $z_1=t,  z_2=y(t)$, hence
$z_1'=1, z_2'=t y'(t)=t z_2$ , which isn't autonomous. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is a trick, just add the ODE $\dot{t} = 1$, $t_0 = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't really get it, could you explain

Comment: Instead of $\dot{x} = f(x,t)$ you have $\dot{x} = f(x,y)$ and $\dot{y} = 1$, with initial condition $y(t_0) = t_0$ for $y$. You can see that $y(t) = t$ always.